# Why is this action not waiting to return the response

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, action

I have the following, which I am calling from a component

```
const getUserAction = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(request());
    return getUser()
      .then(
        response => {
          dispatch(success());
          console.log(response);
          return response
        },
        error => {
          dispatch(failure(error));          
        }
      )
  };
};
```

Then on the component, I am dispatching this action:

```
this.props.dispatch(getUserAction())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
}
```

I am seeing the console log from the above component being fired *before* the console log from the action.

Why is this? Am I doing something wrong or is this the expected behavior? Why does the console log from the action wait for the response, and the return statement from the same action doesn't wait?

And then, how can I get the response in my component if not going through the reducer?

Comment: Use callback instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const getUserAction = (cb) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(request());
    return getUser()
      .then(
        response => {
          dispatch(success());
          console.log(response);
          // success callback with response
          cb(null /** no error hence null */, response) 

          return response
        },
        error => {
          dispatch(failure(error));          
        }
      )
  };
};
```

Call like this:

```
this.props.dispatch(getUserAction((err, success) => {
   if(err){
     // Handle error here
     return;
   }, 
   // Success handle 
   console.log(response))
}));
```